# SQL: alias on field at time of creation

Tags: sql, naming-conventions, alias

Can you create an alias on field at time of creation? Example

```
 CREATE TABLE MYTABLE (                                           
    VERY_LONG_NAME       AS VLN  INT     NOT NULL )
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No.**

Why create a table with a `VERY_LONG_NAME` and then alias it? Simply choose `A_BETTER_NAME` to begin with.

In addition, it would be quite confusing to have a DB where columns are accessible by multiple names. How would you know which name was the actual name and which was the aliased name?

**EDIT**

As per @DavidFabers suggestion, if you **must** name your column `VERY_LONG_NAME`, you could create a view to allow you/users to access the column by a shorter name:

```
CREATE VIEW [vwMyTable] AS 
    SELECT  VERY_LONG_NAME AS A_BETTER_NAME
    FROM    MyTable
```

Comment: Agreed with the above. If you must do something of this sort then create a friendly view that end-users and developers can use. E.g. `CREATE VIEW myfriendlyview AS SELECT very_long_name AS vln FROM myunfriendlytable`.